# What type of sentence is this?

Tags: types-of-sentences

I want to know whether the following sentence is complex or compound.

> **We must not be late, else we will miss the train.**

Comment: Why do you want to know this?  What have you done to answer this question yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to pick one or the other, I'd say it's a **complex** sentence since the two parts of the sentence are not truly independent of each other.  The second part is offered as a hypothetical consequence of the first part.

However, it could easily be restructured as a *compound sentence*:

> We must not be late, as we don't want to miss the train.

This expresses two related but separate thoughts.